# Design my explorer for an OS in Java

Tags: java, operating-system

I am trying to design my explorer for an OS in Java. It would be something like what "My Computer" does in Windows (obviously with some new features). I have worked with Swing before and maybe I will need to learn a bit of animation programming. Can anyone suggest some good place to get started or some materials perhaps ??

---

Also I will need to communicate with the underlying OS ( I believe so). How  can I do that in Java, as in any platform independent language you are not supposed to use the underlying OS functionality !!

Comment: Ok.. I am on it. What about animation programming ?? I want to have some cool effects like when you minimize a window in mac and it moves to the back with a cool transition.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Java is not a good choice of programming language for this task, because (as you noted) it is not good for accessing underlying OS functionality.  However, if you simply want / need to access the file system, then the Java 7 file system APIs may offer you what you need.

Secondly, if you want this "explorer" to run out of a web browser, then you are going to need to write it as a trusted browser plugin, probably in C or C++.

Thirdly, you want to get the basic functionality before you think about cool animation effects.

Finally, you are probably reinventing the wheel.